# Data.SE does not display correct query title for old revisions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, data-explorer

Minor issue: When an existing query on [Data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com) is edited and the title is changed, clicking on previous revisions in the editor displays the new edited title and not the title from that revision.

The title of the query as displayed in user profile pages and the front page does not seem to be affected, but all revisions via https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/QUERY_ID/REVISION_ID show the most recent title.

Steps:

1. Create a new query and run it.
2. Change the title and run it again.
3. Click the first revision in the revision list. Expected: First title displays. Actual: Last revision title displays.

Example: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/176965 (first revision was "Test Query A", second was "Test Query B", final was "Test Query C").

Note that the URL for previous revisions is also changed to reflect the new title.

More typical steps:

1. Pick any query on the main page and visit it.
2. Click "fork query".
3. Change the title (and presumably a user would edit the query too) and run it.
4. Reload the page (it actually doesn't happen initially, only after the revision list is regenerated at least once; reload is the quickest way to show it for this example).
5. Click a previous revision and notice the title is the newest title.

Again, this is a very minor issue. It caught me off guard at first, when I thought I inadvertently changed the title of somebody else's query - but that (fortunately) does not seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Speaking just to the general problem described by the title, this is *kind of* [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign) given that we don't actually save the title/description history anywhere.

But you're right that you aren't actually changing the title of the other person's query. What happens when you fork the original queryset is that the revisions associations get copied over to the new (your) queryset, which causes them to pull back whatever metadata you're using instead of what's stored for the queryset they originated from.

This is probably not ideal, but I'm also not sure how easy it would be to fix, so since it's a fairly minor source of confusion I'm personally going to throw it on the back burner for now.

Comment: As for the (definitely minor) confusion in the forked query case: Maybe, on the UI side, something as straightforward as displaying "forked from" or "copy of" on the first revision in the revision list (or just displaying your username instead of the original author). In my case at least, confusion stemmed from thinking that the initial revision was a reference to the original query ("Did I change the original title?"), rather than a copy of it.