# Data Explorer revert my edit on someone elses query

Tags: support, edits, data-explorer

I have edited / forked a few queries from other users. For example

- [top 100 questions for a given tag without accepted answer](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/459735/951/top-100-questions-for-given-tags-without-an-accepted-answer)
- [number of questions per week given a tag](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/459737/212288/number-of-questions-asked-per-week-given-a-specified-tag)

I changed them quite a bit and thought that this would be part of a fork. But it seems to me that i edited their question, e.g. [when searching](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=Top+100+Questions+for+given+tags+without+an+accepted+answer), the results show only my edits.

How can I revert my edits so that their version is the current one?

Comment: Did you click the "fork" link?

Comment: Related, maybe dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226187/data-se-does-not-display-correct-query-title-for-old-revisions (not sure yet, so not using hammer)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I am not sure if i always clicked the fork link. Regarding the possible duplication i am not sure either; this part `when you fork the original queryset is that the revisions associations get copied over to the new (your) queryset, which causes them to pull back whatever metadata you're using instead of what's stored for the queryset they originated from` it not clear to me. To my understanding the orig query loads the tile from my revision?!

Comment: Yes, looks like SEDE doesn't keep full revisions history, e.g. looks like previous title is just lost. You can ask Tim Stone in a comment, he knows SEDE really well, and these days kind of the only developer SEDE got. (SE developers are not directly touching the SEDE code, only push the changes once in a while when asked for it.)

Comment: Also, Tim is pingable in the Tavern, if you prefer chat over comment. :)